# Display details on list-view by comparing current time and database input time in java android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-listview

I am working on an app that displays the schedule of the bus. I use firebase database, and I input data to the database and retrieve it to the list - view on my app. Currently it shows all data that I input to the database. I want to display the bus details by comparing the current time and input time on the database,by only if the time values are within the range.How to do that? Someone please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
## Firebase ##
when saving your data in firebase add your current timestamp in firebase

## App ##

When retrieve from Firebase get your device current timestamp and compare with timestamp

DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference eventsReference = databaseReference.child("bus");

Query query = eventsReference.orderByChild("timestamp").startAt("device_current_timestamp");
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener).....
```